# IOS: How to retrieve username/password from keychain to uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my application, user will login in the IOS side that parsing from PHP api and after login have UIWebView that use same username/password.

I've stored username/password at *ViewController* this is where the login page. How can i retrieve username/password from keychain to uiwebview that located at *WebViewController*?

Some suggestion i found is to use javascript to identify elements and populate values. May i know how to do it? And last question, how to keep the session alive even though the app was closed using keychain?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GenericKeyChainSample from apple.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html